# What is NoSQL stack for React.js?

Tags: reactjs, nosql

I want to know if there is a `NoSQL` library or framework stack for `React.js` just like `Angular` and `MongoDB`. I dont really understand flux. So any comment will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

flux is an application state container. Not something like `mongoDB`.
Flux lets you have an application wide state, not dissimilar to react component state.
`mongoDB` is a DB that persists. Only data that defines current application state should go into the flux store. It does NOT persist.

**Application state example**
Suppose you are using react to build a game using multiple components.
React components have a uni directional flow of data from parent to child as props.
So if the child component decides to advance you to next level, all it has to do is, change the game level stored in **application state** and the parent component can read from the store and do the needful for new level.

Flux is basically a library that makes it easier to have an application wide state. Since the component state is limited to a single component.
There is another library that helps you manage application state called redux. http://redux.js.org/
It's easy to understand :)

PS: You can use mongoDB or Redis or any DB for that matter in your backend. Flux is not your db. Personally, I'd rather use Redis.
I believe angular is a framework. Whereas React is a library. You have the freedom to choose the technologies you want to pair it up with.

Comment: Thank you very much @jeffpc 1993, at least my mind is clear about NoSQL.

Comment: glad to have been of help :)